# Changing date format from html to mysql (best practice?)

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

The situation is as follows: my mysql database has date in unix time (for example: 1440514020), and my html page sends dates like this: 30/02/2015.

If I do this:

```
mysql> select date(from_unixtime(1440514020));
```

I get that:

```
2015-08-25
```

So, of course, I can't directly use my html's webpage dates on mysql, because the date format isn't compatible, so my question is: which would be better, use `select date_format(from_unixtime(1440514020), '%d/%m/%Y');`, or use jquery/php to change the date before sending it to mysql?

Edit: There's also the option to change how dates are stored altogether, so I can make an update for all actual dates, and then a trigger to put all dates on the d/m/Y format.

Comment: major of the JQuery plugin has an option for date format, and I prefer DB date as Y-m-d, so you can set the date to Y-m-d in both db and jQuery

Comment: @RaunakGupta And that's the thing. I have at least 3 ways to deal with it. mysql's date_format, using a simple php function, or using jquery. I'm asking which one is the best way to do it, just out of curiosity, and which are the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Best practise in to keep DB date in **`Y-m-d`** format and in frontend
>   wherever needed you can display it by changing its format.

And in your datepicker you can set the date format as `Y-m-d` and with PHP script you can query into db.